# How to train an LSTM model on multi-dimentional array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I recently wrote an LSTM model to predict sequence:

```
    ############### BUILD MODEL ###############

''' HERE WE ARE CREATING THE LSTM MODEL '''

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X.shape[1:]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(X.shape[1:]), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# In[8]:


'''HERE WE ARE CREATING AN OPTIMIZER AND THEN TRAINING OUR MODEL'''

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=10, epochs=1)
```

where `np.shape(X) = (237, 30, 3)` and `np.shape(Y) = (237, 3)`. But while fitting this data to the model it is returning an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (3,)
```

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: You can print out input and output shape of each layer of your model by `model.summary()`. Then you can check which layer is `dense_1` and what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data shapes are as some thing like this: np.shape(X) = (237, 30, 3) and np.shape(Y) = (237, 3)
try this network.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(X.shape[1:]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=10, epochs=1)
```

Since you are using [Keras Sequential Api](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) you don't have to specify the input for second LSTM layer, and at the final Dense layer your "Y" shape is (237, 3) so final Dense layer should also be giving out 3 as well.

You can also give input_shape=(None, 3) for you first LSTM layer if "3"(number of features) in your input is constant for every sample.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have one-hot encoded the labels. Either don't one-hot encode them (i.e. let them be sparse labels) and use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function or alternatively, one-hot encode them and use `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function.

As a side note: are you sure it is a classification task? Since you are using a softmax layer as the last layer with 10 units but you mentioned that the labels have 3 classes?!